# Актуальная компиляция PHP

Tags: php, компиляция, компилятор

На данный момент PHP активно развивается, использовать его только в качестве разработки сайтов не есть рационально. Мне стало интересно, можно ли скомпилировать скрипт, что бы пользователь выполнил его без интерпретатора PHP. Оказалось можно, только компиляторы которые я находил устаревшие. А мне бы хотелось поюзать ООП. Хотя бы от версии 5.4. Какой на данный момент актуальный компилятор?
GUI не нужно, консольного варианта хватает с головой.

Answer (score 2):

Не надо заниматься извращениями. Понимая под "компиляцией" создание исполняемого файла под виндоус, следует понимать, что исполняемый файл под виндоус - это в первую очередь поддержка оконного интерфейса. Которой в пхп не было и не будет.